# Multiple operators in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Scenario: I have multiple columns in a table e.g. customer ID, customer Name, City, Invoice amount, paid amount.

I want to create a slicer based on invoice amount, where I can filter the data based on invoice amount column as below:
Amount 5000-200000 - Slicer Option should show text "Low"
Amount 200000 - 1000000  - Slicer Option should show text "Medium"
Amount 1000000 - any higher amount - Slicer Option should show "High"

I tried using Dax If ( or ( ... ) ) but it is not working.
Since I am new to Power BI so don't know if I should create a measure a column or a table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "New Column" in the Table, using "Table tools":
[image]

Introduce this code:

```
AmountType = if(Table[Amount]>1000000,"High",if(Table[Amount]<200000,"Low","Medium"))
```

Then use AmountType in the slicer.

Note that if you need to exclude those with Amount < 5000 from the category "Low" you would have to add it to the if statement:

```
if(AND(Sheet1[Amount]<200000,Sheet1[Amount]>100000),"Medium","Low")
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I am half way there. The only thing missing is I want to use amount ranges in the dax. Some thing like

if(Table[Amount]>1000000 AND <= 2000000 
so that when I select Low from the "Low" slicer, it can show the amounts between 100000 and 200000.

I tried using || but it's not working

Comment: In that case you can use AND(condition 1, condition 2). For example: AND(Table[Amount]<200000,Table[Amount]>100000).